# How can I debug what apears to be an authentication issue with a custom field on the contact object in salesforce?

Tags: debugging, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

First, thank you in advance for your assistance.  I am relatively new to apex, but not to programming.  So, while I will apreciate if someone has the answer right off the bat, I'm as equally interested in how I would have debugged this to find the answer.  So, to the issue...

I have a controller which based of query string values from a VF page builds a SOQL statement and returns a result set of contacts.  The result set is then return in JSON format.  When I run this inside of force.com, as test for the controller, it works correctly...

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/');
Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
MyController con = new MyController ();
pr.getParameters().put('action', 'search');
System.debug(con.JsonString);
```

This returns

```
{"SearchResults":[***ARRAY OF MANY CONTACT RECORDS***],"PaginationInfo":
{"RecordsPerPage":10,"TotalRecords":5,"TotalPages":1,"PageNumber":1}}
```

If I view this outside of force.com, via a link to the VF page like this:
    https://mysite.secure.force.com/requestpage?action=search

It also dumps the json correctly.  I'm running into a problem when I access a custom field.  If I run the same test above adding the field, everything still works correctly in force.com.

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/');
Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
MyController con = new MyController ();
pr.getParameters().put('action', 'search');
pr.getParameters().put('specialty', 'a0xH0000001u5YtIAI');
System.debug(con.JsonString);
```

Runnig the above in a test against the controller spits out a JSON object with multiple contact records.  However, when I do the external call adding the parameter, https://mysite.secure.force.com/requestpage?action=search&specialty=a0xH0000001u5YtIAI, I get an empty result set.

```
{"SearchResults":[],"PaginationInfo":
{"RecordsPerPage":10,"TotalRecords":null,"TotalPages":null,"PageNumber":1}}
```

So, my first thought is that there is some kind of authentication issue with the field since my tests within the controller actually does return a result set.  Basically, controller with me logged in as admin running a test, works.  VF page, accessed externally from a site as a guest user, does not work, but only for that field.  If I do the first request above, where I'm not filtering by the field, it does return contact objects.  Moreover, the fact that a json object is being returned leads me to believe there are no exceptions occuring in the code.  I spent a few hours last night trying to figure out field level authentication.  Based on some posts, I went to the site in force.com, to the public access settings, custom field level security, and edited the section to what I believe should be correct. All fields in there are checked as visible.  Not sure how 'read only' works there.  I tried include a picture buy my level doesn't allow me to.

I also attempted to research how one could see error logging in force.  I've openned the developer console and also tried to setup debug logging, however I just can't seem to figure out how I can use those tools to debug my situation.  So, can someone point me in the right direction?  One last note, although I feel this is probably an authentication issue, perhaps I'm missing something and it's a code issue.  It's hard to tell since when I run the tests it doesn't fail.  Again, thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Important note: I did not use the actual force.com page in my post above.  I just put an example of a link to a VF page so you get an idea of the flow: VF Page that can be seen externally from a site.

Comment: This looks like a permission issue, but as you stated it can be hard to debug.
I would start creating a test case and running the JSON export with the parameters using the site user profile (see [runAs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm)).